# PHP - easiest way to get $_GET parameters string as written in the URL

Tags: php

I'm trying to redirect from one page to another while retaining the parameters.

e.g. if I have a page page.php?param1=1&param2=2, what's the easiest way to extract "param1=1&param2=2"?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Use `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']` to access everything after the question mark.

So if you have the url:

```
http://www.sample.com/page.php?param1=1&param2=2
```

then this:

```
$url = "http://www.sample.com/page2.php?".$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
echo $url;
```

will return:

```
http://www.sample.com/page2.php?param1=1&param2=2
```

Answer (score 9):

In addition to Robs answer:

You can use [http_build_query](http://php.net/manual/de/function.http-build-query.php) and $_GET.
This is build-in and can deal with arrays.
Also you can easily manipulate the GET params this way, befor you put them together again.

```
unset($_GET['unsetthis']);
$query = http_build_query($_GET);
```

Answer (score 7):

`$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']`

[Source](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php)

Answer (score 5):

i would do

```
$querystring = '?'
foreach($_GET as $k=>$v) {
    $querystring .= $k.'='.$v.'&';
}
$url .= substr($querystring, 0, -1);
```

where `$url` already contains everything before the ?

you could also use `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']` but as per the PHP manual:

> $_SERVER is an array containing information such as headers, paths, and script locations. The entries in this array are created by the web server. ***There is no guarantee that every web server will provide any of these; servers may omit some, or provide others not listed here. ***

Comment: That's technically true, but whatever web server he's using almost certainly provides `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']`; most PHP-based systems rely on it existing

Comment: this will also not render arrays like: `key[innerkey]=value` . it will get you: `key=Array`