# GET complicated URL parameter in PHP

Tags: php, url, redirect

Hello I am trying to get a parameter (a url) from a php code using GET

```
<?php
      $url = $_GET['url'];
```

and it was triggered using

```
http://localhost/run.php?url=www.google.com
```

in this case `$url` equals `www.google.com`

However if the url contains "&" it won't work.  For example:

```
http://localhost/run.php?url=www.google.com?action=Go&category=3&name=foo%20bar
```

In this case $url equals `www.google.com?action=Go` and omits everything after the first "&".

How to fix this without needing to modify the actual URL?  My goal is to pass the entire url including all the parameters as a string to $url.  And since the url is dynamically generated I cannot predict which parameters will be used.

Comment: `$_GET['url']` != `$_GET['link']`. Your first example is faulty. You don't have a GET paramter called `url`, it's `link`.

Comment: `?link=www.google.com?action=` is invalid, remove the second `?`

Comment: You need to urlencode the link parameter. in javascript  `encodeURIComponent`

Comment: @kerbholz Edited the original code. It should be $url all along.  The thing is that is exactly what to do, include all the parameters in the URL and passed it as a string to $url

Comment: @Tschallacka can I not touch javascript and achieve the same result?

Comment: like I said, urlencode if you output the url via php. `$url = 'http://localhost/run.php?url=' . urlencode('www.google.com?action=Go&category=3&name=foo%20bar');`

Answer (score 0):

The Wikipedia article about GET states that:

> This is a format for encoding key-value pairs with possibly duplicate
>   keys. Each key-value pair is separated by an '&' character, and each
>   key is separated from its value by an '=' character.
>   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POST_(HTTP)

Because the '&' is used to seperate the values it omits everything after (or stores it in the next key-value-pair to be exact).

Hope that helps.

Comment: Is there any way to get around this? Assuming the url is dynamic and I cannot predict how many parameters will be included in the url.

Comment: One way would be to just copy the whole $_GET in a local string and split it yourself. Maybe you find this interesting: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3141708/php-easiest-way-to-get-get-parameters-string-as-written-in-the-url

Answer (score -1):

I found a way to do that now.

```
$url= $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
```

Will capture the complete URL after the first "?" sign to $url. Then all I need to do is to remove the "url=" from $url